# How to send email from template using RazorEngine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-email, razorengine

I am trying to use a `.cshtml` template to send an email with RazorEngine. The documentation on [their site](http://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/) shows how to use it with a string containing the razor syntax. How would I go about using it by loading a `.cshtml` file instead?

This is what I have

```
    string templatePath = "~/Templates/InitialApplicationBody.cshtml";
    var result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(templatePath, "templateKey", null, viewModel);
```

Answer (score 4):

From a MVC Controller, it's easy to generate HTML from a Razor view (CSHTML file).

I have successfully used code from the accepted answer to [Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string), putting it in a base controller.

```
// Renders a Razor view, returning the HTML as a string
protected string RenderRazorViewToString<T>(string viewName, T model) where T : class
{
    ViewData.Model = model;

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
      var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                                                           viewName);

      var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                        ViewData, TempData, sw);

      viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
      viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);

      return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Mailzory](https://github.com/mirsaeedi/Mailzory) project is a convenient choice for sending emails which have Razor templates. Mailzory uses RazorEngine behind the scene.

```
// template path
var viewPath = Path.Combine("Views/Emails", "hello.cshtml");
// read the content of template and pass it to the Email constructor
var template = File.ReadAllText(viewPath);

var email = new Email(template);

// set ViewBag properties
email.ViewBag.Name = "Johnny";
email.ViewBag.Content = "Mailzory Is Funny";

// send email
var task = email.SendAsync("mailzory@outlook.com", "subject");
task.Wait()
```

this project is hosted at Github. Also there is a [nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/Mailzory/) available for Mailzory.